# sql server division precision

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view and I want to divide columnA/columnB. Both columns are decimals. However, I don't get the precision I need. I get only 6 values after the decimal point and I want to get all of them.

For example 3163.82/240008.56 = 0.013182 and I want to get 0.0131821131712969.
I tried CAST, ROUND and still I get the same result.

Comment: What data type definition for these columns?

Comment: For reference, the method SQL Server uses to determine a `numeric`/`decimal` precision and scale when used in an expression is [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks), with the scale being `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)` for division. In this case, that results to `MAX(6,2+8+1) = MAX(6,11) = 11`. This does not match the value you say you get (`0.013182`) and I agree; `SELECT 3163.82/240008.56` returns `0.01318211317` (scale of 11). Even with `real` and `float`, I can't get the value you state you get.

Comment: It seems in one of the previous steps ColumnA and B are multiplied by -1, if the value is negative. This didn't work `cast(colA/colB as decimal(30,20))`,returns 0.01318200000000000000.  This works `cast(colA as decimal(30,20))/colB`, returns 0.01318211317129689041090867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do cast before dividing. Something like

```
cast(3163.82 as decimal(30,20)) / 240008.56
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/4c3SmjSB